Python 3, API call issue
Using a Raspberry PI 3 to connect to MBTA API
I am using a raspberry pi 3 to call the MBTA transit API to obtain updated information for stop IDs. I have a code that calls the API and pulls out the stop ID data. I had all of this working before until a few days ago. The problem is only with the Red line for the MBTA. But when I run my script it gives me this error message.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "APItest.py", line 23, in <module>
  currentstop[i] = stop_name(test[i]['id'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Which is strange to me because it works when I call the blue line stop locations, I don't change the code at all when doing this other than the API I call. I am posting the python 3 code below. This is the call for the Redline. The only thing I change when calling the blue line is change the variable "line" to 'Blue'.
import requests
import json
from APIstops import stop_name

APIkey = '--------------------------' # My personal API access Key
line = 'Red' # Line will be testing with first
URL2 = "https://api-v3.mbta.com/vehicles?filter[route]=" + line  + "&api_key=" + APIkey # URL for calling red line specific
vehicles = requests.get(URL2) # gets vehicle data from API
dataV = vehicles.text # converts to text
parse_json = json.loads(dataV) # parses data to JSON format
MBTAV = parse_json['data'] # creates array of parsed data
vehicle_locals = dict() # creates a dictionary of current location of red line vehicles
test = dict()

for vehicle in MBTAV:
    vehicle_locals[vehicle['id']] = vehicle['relationships']['stop']['data'] # stores current stop for each train per given line
#print(vehicle_locals)
for i in range(0 , len(vehicle_locals)):
    test[i] = list(vehicle_locals.values())[i]
print(test[0]['id'])
currentstop = [None] * len(vehicle_locals)
for i in range(0, len(vehicle_locals)):
    currentstop[i] = stop_name(test[i]['id'])
print(currentstop)

I don't know why it works for Blue and not Red. I have looked at the APIs and they both look the same.
I honestly don't know what else to try.
the MBTA API URL for the Red line
https://api-v3.mbta.com/vehicles?filter[route]=Red
the MBTA API URL for the Blue line
https://api-v3.mbta.com/vehicles?filter[route]=RedBlue

The error is telling you that test[i] is None (in a roundabout way. It's actually you that you're using the subscript operator [...] on something that isn't a dict), so: print test to find out what elements are in there after you fill it.

Simply: sometimes a vehicle's stop data is "stop":{"data":null}:

so you end up with None in the dictionary, and trying to work on that is a no-go.
With some simplification, and that filtering added in, your script becomes
import requests

APIkey = "..."  # My personal API access Key
line = "Red"  # Line will be testing with first
resp = requests.get(
    "https://api-v3.mbta.com/vehicles",
    params={
        "filter[route]": line,
        # "api_key": APIkey,  # uncomment if you have an API key
    },
)
resp.raise_for_status()
MBTAV = resp.json()["data"]
vehicle_locals = {
    vehicle["id"]: vehicle["relationships"]["stop"]["data"]
    for vehicle in MBTAV
    if vehicle["relationships"]["stop"]["data"] is not None
}
print(vehicle_locals)

and outputs
{
    "R-547CC0EE": {"id": "70094", "type": "stop"},
    "R-547CC0E0": {"id": "70088", "type": "stop"},
    "R-547CC0D8": {"id": "70089", "type": "stop"},
    "R-547CBFEF": {"id": "70077", "type": "stop"},
    "R-547CBFA0": {"id": "70071", "type": "stop"},
    "R-547CBF3F": {"id": "70064", "type": "stop"},
    "R-547CBD8D": {"id": "70065", "type": "stop"},
    "R-547C9415": {"id": "70072", "type": "stop"},
    "R-547C5517": {"id": "70078", "type": "stop"},
}

(I don't have your APIstops module and therefore your stop_name() function, so that's elided from here.)
